# Issue in alphabetic sorting in mysql records

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have table with 1000+ keywords.

Table definition
keyword
keyword_id

[Please note collation and charset is utf-8]

keyword can be alphabets, with UTE-8 characters like "α- inhibitors" and "25 hyrdoglucose"... So they are mix of alphabets, number and special characters.

To sort the above

> select * from kword order by keyword + 0 ASC

To keep alphabets on top and digits/special char at the end.

When from the html  when I try adding new keyword , the newly added keyword start coming in mid of result set !..

Example:

Abacus
Abaximal
A...
A...
A...
.......till 50 first keyword

After adding "Biomatrix". The same query return

Abacus
Abaximal
A...
A....
Biomatrix
A....
.....till 50 keyword

Any idea whats wrong with query or what is other way to sort the mysql records when you have such a mix of characters.

Regards,

Comment: What happens if you lose the `+0`?

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying a sort that puts the alpha characters first and then the numbers, with the numbers sorted in order.  There is no rule about how the alpha characters are being sorted.

If you want the alpha characters first in alphabetical order:

```
order by keyword + 0 ASC, keyword
```

If you want the alpha characters first in reverse insert order:

```
order by keyword + 0 ASC, keyword_id desc;
```

If you want the alpha characters first in reverse insert order followed by the numbers in reverse insert order:

```
order by (left(keyword, 1) between '0' and '9') desc,
         keyword_id desc;
```

Note that the last two assume that `keyword_id` is an auto-incremented column used as a proxy for the insert order.